# How to handle updated readme that I never pulled?

Tags: git, github

I updated my  readme.md using the GitHub interface and then made a number of local commits without ever pulling the changes made to the remote repository.

Now when I try to push the local changes I get an error:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git
>   pull ...') before pushing again.

Similarly, when I pull I get an error:

> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

What is the simplest way to handle this problem using Git?

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking of a title over here guys. If somebody can think of a better one please edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve the conflicts using `git mergetool`, commit and push.

Read more about Merge Conflicts here: [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: I have know clue what IDE you are using, but your IDE might have a nice merge tool built in (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA)